# Test that middleware was used in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, middleware

I  have a post route inside a middleware that checks whether a user performing a request belongs to a specific role. I have 4 roles in total. And I have found it silly  to write tests like :

- testRole2CanNotDoAction
- testRole3CanNotDoAction
- testRole4CanNotDoAction

every time I want to test some action. So it would be really nice if I can just write 1 test

- testMiddlewareWasCalled

to assure that route is placed in right place. How can I do it? To give you the context lets assume I have the following middleware:

```
class MustBeRole1
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        if ($user && $user->isRole1()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'You are not an role1!');
    }
}
```

and following routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['isRole1']], function () {
    Route::post('/testAction', ['as' => 'testAction', 'uses' => 'testActionController@test']);
}
```

How should my test look like?